# How to get Members of GroupMailboxes in PowerShell Exchange

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to get the Members of my groupMailboxes. I already wrote a script for sharedMailboxes that works well. If I want to apply the same for groupMailboxes I get an error.

```
Get-Mailbox -GroupMailbox | Get-Mailboxpermission -GroupMailbox
```

The Error I get is that all the groupMailboxes aren't found as
recipient.

This is how I did it for sharedMailboxes which works fine.

```
Get-Mailbox -Filter {recipienttypedetails -eq "SharedMailbox"} | Get-Mailboxpermission
```

This is another way I tried to implement it.

```
Get-Mailbox -GroupMailbox -Filter {recipienttypedetails -eq "GroupMailbox"} | Get-Mailboxpermission -GroupMailbox
```

Here I get the same error that the groupMailboxes can't be found as recipients.
The error dosen't make sense to me, because I clearly get the GroupMailboxes from the Get-Mailbox command. How cant these Mailboxes be found for the Mailboxpermisson command then?

Comment: Perhaps you should try `Get-Recipient -RecipientTypeDetails GroupMailbox` and go from there?

Comment: sadly it produces the same error.
```
Get-Recipient -RecipientTypeDetails GroupMailbox | Get-Mailboxpermission -GroupMailbox 
```

Comment: For clarity, are you trying to identify which members are groups?, If so this will not be possible from the results of `Get-Mailboxpermission` alone as the property set of this object does not specify the member type. You are likely going to have to store the output of `Get-Mailbox` and iterate through the users that are in the results of `Get-Mailbox -Filter {recipienttypedetails -eq "SharedMailbox"} | Get-Mailboxpermission` to identify member type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:
Get-EXORecipient -ResultSize unlimited | where RecipientTypeDetails  -eq "GroupMailbox" | foreach { if (Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $*.ExternalDirectoryObjectId | where DisplayName -Match "xyz") {Write-Host $*.Name}}